# Manipulating Images in Windows Surface 2.0 (rotation)

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I am using c# wpf for windows surface 2.0.

I have been working with a set of images that i import in the xmpl file.

I found some examples for text, but for the images they used GDI+ to manipulate images and animate them, but I do not want that.

The main thing that I want to do now is to rotate(transform rotate) an image and show that it is rotating.

Here is how I am addressing the images:

```
Canvas.SetTop(image1, 0);
Canvas.SetLeft(image1, 200);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What you are using is not WPF but it uses XAML, better call it WinRT-XAML, And what do you mean by Surface 2.0

Comment: ok, thank you @VibeeshanRC, Microsoft Surface 2.0 is the second surface edition (next-generation Microsoft Surface), is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Can you put your image in a `ScatterViewItem`?

Comment: @VibeeshanRC The question is about what is now called PixelSense (formerly known as Surface). It is WPF. I have removed those other tags.

Comment: @vanlalhriata, yes I can put it in scatter view.

Comment: @clemens, thank your edit and reply

Comment: @Vanlalhriata, I am not sure about disabling, let me check and reply, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very specific and there are a lot of ways to animate the rotation of an image.

A simple approach would be to assign a `RotateTransform` to the `RenderTransform` of your Image controls and then animate the `Angle` property of these RotateTransforms.

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="..."
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Start the animation in code like this:

```
var transform = (RotateTransform)image.RenderTransform;
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(360, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
```

---

You may start reading about animations in WPF in the [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) article on MSDN. The [Transforms Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx) article may also be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much, I never considered this approach, let me try it. And thank you for the links

Comment: you are epic my friend, thank you very much, this is pretty much what i want :)

Comment: If I may ask another question regarding Rotate, is it possible to make the image rotate even more from the current angle it is set on?
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There are however the `To` and `From` properties, and also a `RepeatBehaviour`. Please have a look at the `Animation Overview` link in the answer.

Comment: thank you for the RepeatBehaviour link, if you dont mind me asking one more question, which is: How can I use and control RepeatBehaviour via the cs code? Or should I start a new thread for this question?

Comment: You may just set `animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;`.

Comment: One last thing @Clemens, sorry for being a bother, but I am trying to pause the animation and restart it multiple times, so I have looked up and I have found animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Count(1);
but this gives syntax error.
also is there a way to make "var animation" a global variable?

Comment: Perhaps it's time to learn C#. You may make `animation` a member (a field) of your (Window?) class. Setting a RepeatBehavior with Count = 1 is not necessary, as it is the default. Setting some other value would involve a call like `animation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(3);`.

Comment: Yes I understand that @Clemens, but what i am trying to do is to invoke rotation separately, in the sense it should not rotate the image until I ask it, so I cant have it turn x number of time in a row, so is there a way around that?
Also thank you for the member of the field hint.

Comment: You mean you want to stop it at any time after you started it? You may just call `transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, null);`.

Comment: thank you very much @Clemens, you keep saving me friend, this is exactly what i am looking for, really thank you.

Comment: ok, I am taking your advice regarding the sites, but i keep having specific questions rather than general ones, are there any sites that you would recomend for me to check beside the ones you already mentioned @Clemens.
for example resuming rotation from a certain angle, i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674369/pausing-an-animation-rotation-setting-the-angle-value-then-resuming-later
but still couldnt adapt to it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rotate your image automatically and without user interaction, check Clemens' answer. However if you want to rotate with touch manipulations, I find it easy to put the image in a `ScatterViewItem` like so:

```
<s:ScatterView>
    <s:ScatterViewItem CanMove="False" CanScale="False">
        <s:ScatterViewItem.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="yourImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </s:ScatterViewItem.Background>
    </s:ScatterViewItem>
</s:ScatterView>
```

Of course, you have the overhead of having to put in a `ScatterView` and its content

Comment: Alright, will test this also, thank you very much @Vanlalhriata

Comment: You may even combine both solutions. Put the images in ScatterViewItem controls in order to allow the user to manipulate them. When you need to programmatically manipulate the images, just animate the ScatterViewItem's `Orientation` (and perhaps `Center`) properties.

Comment: Both of them are working nicely, thanks for the hint @Clemens.